# Add background color to active menu item with css

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

How to add background color to the active menu item with css (ie when I click on about link and go to about page I want that active menu item have red background)?

This is my code in Wordpress:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                                        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'
                                ) ); ?>
                              </ul>
                            </nav>
```

and this is my css:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:visited {
    background: red !important;
}
```

But this css targets and "hover elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I think WordPress CMS toggles automatically a `active` class or something similar to that. So you can target only that one class. It would be nice if you could provide a snippet of already generated navigation bar HTML.

Comment: You were right, thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress menus output this class with the list item: current-menu-item so you can use this method to target active menu items:

```
li.current-menu-item {
    background: $sec-color;
}
```

If your theme supports the creation of multiple navigation menus, then you’ll need to be a bit more specific in your CSS

```
#menu-main-pages li.current-menu-item {
background: #3FAEA5;
color:#fff;
}
```

source:
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-highlight-the-current-page-when-using-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Comment: How to change the color wher hover over the navbar item ?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at some WordPress sites, so there are several options you could try, because I don't know which class your WordPress installation triggers if a menu item is active.

**Option 1:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.current-page-item > a{
   background: red;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a{
   background: red;
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li a.current {
   background: red;
 }
```